# Issue with images in different browsers

Tags: html

I am having trouble with the rendering of images. In Chrome, It looks beautiful, But Firefox and IE makes it look all edgy. What can I do? The attached image shows the Firefox render on the left side and the Chrome render on the right side.

```
<img src="../Media/Images/GD%20Logo%20Transparent.png" alt="Company Logo" height="35px" style="padding-bottom:10px;"/>
```

The Render Image:
[image]

Comment: I'm sorry if you can't see the difference too well from the image attached, But I assure you there is a huge difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you use resized image `height="35px"`.  Make image with width of 35px an use it without resizing.

Comment: Is there no alternative apart from resizing the physical image?

Comment: Make a second image, named logo_small.png, which is 35px high, and keeps the logo.png original.

Comment: +1; this is probably the correctly answer. Sending a larger image than is required is considered poor practice for whole range of reasons. You should resize it.

Comment: I think different browsers use different resizing algorithms (for example bilenear, bicubic) and there aren't way to specify it by markup or styles.

Comment: @YD1m Firefox's current resizing algorithm is a lot better than it used to be, though, unless my memory of jaggy lines on scaled-down images comes from IE rather than old Firefox.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using an PNG image with a transparent background, some browsers won't render it correctly.  In this case, as the image is on a solid background, you can just fill the background of your PNG with the background colour of the page.